# HTTPClient and JWT Authentication in C#

Tags: c#, jwt

I'm having a hard time trying to use authorization in C# Winforms. My purpose is to access the API. I already get the access token but when I try to pass it to the header, it returns an error:

> HTTP error 400.

My code:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var url = @"https://acerportal.com/v1/414232363/status/device/";
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", accessToken);

    var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
    string checkResult = response.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(checkResult);
}
```

Comment: If "Basic" isn't working try "Bearer" because "Bearer" is the default scheme for JWT in aspnetcore at the time of writing this.

Comment: Please note:  An HttpClient should NOT be used inside a using block.  https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The header has to look a little different, the format is `Authorization: <type> <credentials>` - so it's like this for jwt:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
```

For an explanation, also see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re

Comment: i still get the bad request when using that.

Comment: likely the problem is elsewhere then - are you sure the token is actually valid?

Answer (score 0):

Hi already solve the problem by simply removing "Bearer" on the inputs.